# Updated Config Vars are not reflected on website

Tags: heroku

If I update config vars changes are not populated to website. I need to redeploy the application to see changes.
The interesting part is it worked without redeploying before and we have not changed anything since that time.

Here's example of updating from cmd
[image]

Are there options that define that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Config variable changes lead to dyno restarts, always.

Only thing I can think of is [preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot), which can lead to some minutes of time between the config-change and the change actually being visible in the web-application.